# My confusion: reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, rtti, instanceof

I've just finished reading the chapter of 'Thinking in Java' concerning type information and reflection. While `instanceof` seems quite natural to me, some examples of reflection made me confused. I want to know if reflection is widely used in Java projects? What are 'the good parts' of reflection? Can you suggest any interesting lectures about reflection and type information with more good and worthy examples?

Edit (one more question):

Why is it useful to access private methods and fields with`java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccesible()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can also post some example that are confusing you we can all discuss about that.

Comment: For example: http://pastebin.com/3whc59LN It illustrates dynamic proxy to create a Null Object. Is is popular solution? It seemed strange to me

Comment: Maciel. Think about this scenario: You have only the binaries for some Class, one of the private fields of an object of this class is holding a incorrect value, and/or you need to call a private method of one object for whatever reason. You can then set them both as accessible, change the variable value and invoke the private method using reflection. Of course this violates OO principles and have it's drawbacks (access the link for Oracle Trails in my answer and read about Exposure of Internals), but it is indeed useful.

Comment: I will use your link, thanks!

Comment: @see Uses of Reflection: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you could post some of the examples I would be glad to explain it for you.
Reflection is wildly used with frameworks that need to extract meta-info about the running object (e.g. frameworks which depends on Annotations or the fields in your objets, think about Hibernate, Spring and a lot others).
On a higher layer, I sometimes use reflection to provide generic functionality (e.g. to encode every String in an object, emulate Duck Typing and such).
I know that you already read a book which covers the basics about reflection, but I need to point Sun (erm.. Oracle) official Tutorial as a must read: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3whc59LN This examples illustrates dynamic proxy to create a Null Object. Is is popular solution? It seemed strange to me.

Comment: Think of the code you provided as a dynamic approach to those design patterns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern. Your code is provinding a Null Object, and Proxies in general may be used to decorate objects.

Comment: Hi, the example is quite academic, and yes, proxies are the kind of thing that is often used by frameworks. Think about proxies as a tool to wrap dynamic functionality around a method. For example, Hibernate creates dynamic proxies around your model objects, those proxies fetch lazy associations from the database when you call object.getXXX(). Proxies work like this, they receive the original object and create a new one that, for each targeted method, do something extra before / after or in the place of the original object functionality (invoked at line 45).

Answer (score 2):

One good example in my opinion is instantiating objects based on class names that are known only at runtime, for example contained in a configuration file. 
You will still need to know a common interface to the classes you're dynamically instantiating, so you have something to cast them too. But this lets a configuration drive which implementation will be used.

Comment: 1+. Class.forName("...").newInstance() + ResourceBundle is probably one of the main usages for me (and I forgot to say that in my answer).

Comment: Voted back for mentioning frameworks which I forgot in my answer :) They're pretty heavy users of this method of programming

Answer (score 0):

Another example could be when you have to cast an object to a class that it's a descendant. If you are not sure about the type of that object, you can use instanceof to assure that the cast will be correct at runtime avoiding a class cast exception.

An example:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    Object obj = e.getSource();

    if (obj instanceof objType)
    objType t = (objType) obj;   // you can check the type using instanceof if you are not sure about obj class at runtime
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason to provide such features in Reflection is due to multiple situations where tool/application needs meta information of class, variables, methods. For example:-

1. IDEs using auto completion functionality to get method names and attribute names.
2. Tomcat web container to forward the request to correct module by parsing their web.xml files and request URI.
3. JUnit uses reflection to enumerate all methods in a class; assuming either testXXX named methods as test methods or methods annoted by @Test.

To read full article about reflection you can check http://modernpathshala.com/Forum/Thread/Interview/308/give-some-examples-where-reflection-is-used

Comment: Can we avoid using any shortened URLs. I am afraid to click the link because who knows what is on the other end.